# Running JUnit in Eclipse vs. Terminal/ Command Prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, terminal, command-prompt

#### Explanation -

- I have a java file (`Service.java`) containing multiple methods (`higher(int,int):int` and `isPerfectSquare(int):boolean`).
- I create a test for this class in `ServiceTest.java` containing `testHigher()` and `testIsPerfectSquare()`.
- If there is an compilation error in one of the two methods (in `higher` in my example), Eclipse still runs the tests, showing one pass and one error.
- However, compiling in terminal using the following results in an error.

  ```
   javac -cp out:junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar Service.java ServiceTest.java
  ```
- This means, I cannot execute in terminal using:

  ```
   java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar -class-path . --scan-class-path
  ```

#### Question -

How can one proceed with test execution even with compilation errors in some methods from class under test (like Eclipse does). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

#### Relevant code below -

```java
public class Service {
    public static int higher(int a, int b) { //has compilation error
        if(a > b) {
            return a; 
        }
        if(b > a) {
            return b;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPerfectSquare(int n) {
        return Math.pow((int)Math.sqrt(n), 2) == n;
    }
}
```

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ServiceTest {

    @Test
    void testHigher() {
        assertEquals(5, Service.higher(3, 5));
        assertEquals(6, Service.higher(6, 4));
        assertEquals(7, Service.higher(7, 7));
    }

    @Test
    void testIsPerfectSquare() {
        assertTrue(Service.isPerfectSquare(64));
        assertFalse(Service.isPerfectSquare(63));
    }
}
```

Comment: javac doesn't compile if there is an error. The Eclipse compiler compiles what it canand throws errors at runtime for uncompilable code. So if you want the eclipse behavior on the command line, use the eclipse compiler on the command line. Or simpler, stop trying to run code that contains errors. Just fix the errors first.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet. Its to assess several submissions so unfortunately the compilation errors should not be removed. I looked into Eclipse compilation. If you know how to use it off the top of your head, can you share it? Otherwise, I'll look for it now.

Comment: No, I don't....

Comment: [JDT's documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm) shows how to use Eclipse's compiler on the command line, it might help

Comment: no worries, @JBNizet